# When $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim(X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution, symmetry, exchangeability

Consider a bivariate distribution function $P: \mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow [0,1]$. I have the following question:

Are there ***necessary and sufficient*** conditions **on $P$** (or on its marginals) ensuring that
$$
\exists \text{ a random vector $(X_0,X_1,X_2)$ such that }
$$
$$
(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)\sim P
$$

---

Remarks:

(I) $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$ **does not imply** that some of the random variables among $X_1, X_2, X_0$ are degenerate.

For example, $(X_1-X_0, X_1-X_2)\sim (X_2-X_0, X_2-X_1)\sim (X_0-X_1, X_0-X_2)$ **is implied by** $(X_0, X_1, X_2)$ **exchangeable.**

(II) The symbol "$\sim$" denotes "DISTRIBUTED AS"

---

**My thoughts:** among the **necessary** conditions, I would list the following: let $P_1,P_2$ be the two marginals of $P$. Then it should be that
$$
\begin{cases}
P_1 \text{ is symmetric around zero, i.e., $P_1(a)=1-P_1(-a)$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$}\\
P_2 \text{ is symmetric around zero, i.e., $P_2(a)=1-P_2(-a)$ $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Should $P$ be as well symmetric at zero?

Are these conditions also sufficient? If not, what else should be added to get an exhaustive set of sufficient and necessary conditions?

Comment: Random vectors with more than one dimension don't have CDFs. There are marginal CDFs for the coordinates, but no one CDF for the whole joint distribution.

Comment: If $X_1$ is not degenerate, then a necessary condition is that the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is $0.5$. In the special case where $(X_1, X_2)$ is a bivarate normal this, with the additional requirement that the mean is $(0,0)$, is both necessary and sufficient. It is easy to find counterexamples to sufficiency in the general case (e.g., if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are Rademacher variables then this is not sufficient). Additionally, note that it is necessary that $G_1 = G_2$.

Comment: Since CDFs are right-continuous functions, your symmetry condition insists that the CDF be continuous at $0$ and have value $\frac 12$ at $0$.  @Kodiologist: There exist _joint_ CDFs for random vectors, for example, $F_{X.Y}(x,y) = P\{X \leq x, Y \leq y\}$ where the comma is commonly used to mean intersection. Easier to read than the more formal $$F_{X.Y}(x,y) = P\left(\{X \leq x\}\cap \{Y \leq y\}\right)$$ but YMMV....

Comment: @guy: thanks, I had to modify slightly my question given the confusion in the comments. Could you explain why $G_1=G_2$? Thanks. I can see that my condition implies $X_1-X_0 \sim X_2-X_0\sim X_0-X_1$ and $X_1-X_2 \sim X_2-X_1\sim X_2-X_0$. Why this implies $X_1-X_0\sim X_1-X_2$?

Comment: @user Sorry, I’m not going to go back over your modified question :) I thought the original one was clear enough.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I totally understand. I modified it just because I received confusing comments and I though of clearing them up by slightly changing my question.

Comment: If you have time to provide an answer, I'd be glad to accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to the original version of the question:**

The answer to your question is No except trivially when $(X_1,X_2) = (0,0)$ with probability $1$.  The $(X_1, X_1-X_2) \sim (X_2, X_2-X_1)$ part is easy enough to satisfy (e.g. $X_1, X_2$ are iid normal) but transitivity of $\sim$ implies that $(X_1, X_1-X_2) \sim (-X_1, -X_2)$ which says that $X_1-X_2$ has the same distribution as $-X_2$.  So, $X_1$ must be $0$ with probability $1$, no?  And then
\begin{align}(X_1, X_1-X_2) &\sim (0, -X_2) &\text{as just proven}\\ 
(X_1, X_1-X_2)&\sim (X_2, X_2-X_1) &\text{as given}\\
&\implies X_2 \sim 0 ~\text{ wp } 1\end{align}

Comment: To avoid confusion I've slightly modify my question, adding $X_0$.

Comment: The _marginal_ distributions of $X$ and $Y$ are completely determined by the _joint_ distribution of $X$ and $Y$. a.k.a. the distribution of $(X,Y)$. So, if you assume $(A,B) \sim (X.Y)$, you are implicitly assuming that $A\sim X$ and $B\sim Y$.  Thus, your transitive assumption that $(X_1,X_1-X_2)\sim (-X_1, -X_2)$ is saying that $X_1 \sim -X_1$ which is your symmetry condition on $G_1$ but also that $X_1 - X_2 \sim -X_2$ which can only happen if $X_1$ is $0$ with probability $1$.  Note that your $X_1-X_2 \sim -X_2$ also implies that.$X_1=0$. var($X_1-X_2)=2$, var$(-X_2)=1$ in your example.